# JavaBean to CSV file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

what would be the best way to have information in a JavaBean be put into a CSV file? I am making a registration page and have set all the parameters of my User JavaBean through a JSP page using  I need to store this information into a csv from a servlet everytime someone registers so I can retrieve this information when they use the login JSP page.

Here is my JavaBean

```
package bean.user;

public class User_profile {

 private String First_Name;
 private String Last_Name;
 private String ssn;
 private String birthday;
 private String home_phone;
 private String password;
 private String gender;
 private String email;

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}
public String getFirst_Name() {
return First_Name;
}
public void setFirst_Name(String first_Name) {
First_Name = first_Name;
}
public String getLast_Name() {
return Last_Name;
}
public void setLast_Name(String last_Name) {
Last_Name = last_Name;
}


public String getSsn() {
return ssn;
}
public void setSsn(String ssn) {
this.ssn = ssn;
}
public String getBirthday() {
return birthday;
}
public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
this.birthday = birthday;
}
public String getHome_phone() {
return home_phone;
}
public void setHome_phone(String home_phone) {
this.home_phone = home_phone;
}


public String getPassword() {
return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password = password;
}

public String getGender() {
return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
this.gender = gender;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use introspection to retrieve all the properties of your bean with their corresponding read/write method then call them by reflection.

Here is an example with this simple class:

```
public class User {

  private String login;
  private String name;
  private String surname;
  private Integer age;

  //Getters and setters
}
```

Now, I create a user and dump its properties in a String with comma separated values :

```
User u = new User();
u.setAge(18);
u.setLogin("myLogin");
u.setName("myName");
u.setSurname("mySurname");

for(PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(User.class).getPropertyDescriptors()){
  //I don't want to get the "class" property
  if(!pd.getName().equals("class")){
    Method readMethod = pd.getReadMethod();
    System.out.print(readMethod.invoke(u)+",");
  }
}
```

Output :

```
18,myLogin,myName,mySurname,
```

Note:  For the simplicity of this example, I did not suppress the `','` at the end of the output and did not handle case when properties contain character `','`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jsefa](http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/) if you really really want CSV but this is better suited to store the details in some sort or repository/DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ or any such library which can help you convert your java objects in CSV form. One more for you http://kasparov.skife.org/csv/